# dial tcp: lookup: device or resource busy

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, azure-container-registry

There is an intermittent issue while downloading docker images in a Linux VM. As per docker service journalctl logs I can see below error-

> level=error msg="Handler for POST /images/create returned error: Get
> "https://<containerregistry>": dial tcp: lookup
> https://<containerregistry>: device or resource busy".

Initialy I thought it could be intermittent connectivity issue with container registry (Azure Container Registry) but that is not the case since even with retries at different time periods I got the same error.

I have checked the docker `daemon.json` config and don't see any issue with that. I also verified DNS servers in `systemd-resolve` and can see the expected IPs as required. Interestingly, another VM with same configs works fine.

I am using .Net Client for Docker Remote API (https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet) to trigger docker image updates. The client is hosted in a Linux VM which is triggered by via socket as an RPC call. It reaches the client and executes the API `ImageOperation.CreateImageAsync`.

Can someone help with this? Please let me know if I can add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   Regarding the error that you are encountering, I would suggest you to please **check the azure container registry health first** by executing the below command: -

```
az acr check-health --name registryname --vnet virtualnetworkname
```

Then, **check the internet upload and download speed through ‘AzureSpeed’ tool to the container registry which hosts the images layers**. Also, it may be that the **image size may not be supported for the registry service tier** due to which it is not available.

•   Ensure that **both your ‘docker client’ and ‘docker daemon’ are configured for proxy behavior behind HTTPS proxy**. If you have changed or updated any proxy settings, kindly **ensure to restart the daemon service**.

•   **Check the ‘Registry resource logs in the ContainerRegistryLoginEvents table’ for further diagnosis of an attempted connection**. Also, check whether the **registry is accessible over the internet and allow access to the public registry endpoints from all networks**. If the **container registry is configured for selected virtual network with a service endpoint, then disabling public network access also disables access over the service endpoint**.

•   If a **private endpoint is configured for the container registry, confirm that the DNS resolves the registry's public FQDN such as myregistry.azurecr.io to the registry's private IP address**. Use a **network utility such as ‘dig’ or ‘nslookup’ for DNS lookup**. Ensure that **DNS records are configured for the registry FQDN and for each of the data endpoint FQDNs** as per the below documentation link: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-private-link#dns-configuration-options

•   If a service endpoint to the registry is configured, **confirm that a network rule is added to the registry that allows access from that network subnet**. Also, ensure that the **resource provider for Azure Container Registry is registered**.

For more details regarding the further steps to take to perform regarding the error that you have encountered, kindly refer to the documentation link below: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-troubleshoot-access#configure-service-access